# what is the difference between normal 2012 server and r2 versions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

what is the difference between normal 2012 server and r2 versions.
Is there any speciality on r2 versions
For eg: windows 2012 standard and windows 2012 standard R2

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, R2 is newer - R2 = Release 2.

You can see the summary of changes from 2012 to 2012 R2 on Wikipedia here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012#Changes_from_Windows_Server_2012